# React Native onPress on Android

Tags: android, react-native

Is there any way to show a new file (view) with onPress on TouchableHighlight on android?

Something like :

```
var Details = require(./NewView);

<TouchableHighlight onPress={this.showView()}><TouchableHighlight>

showView(){
   <Details/>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple ways to do this. If you would like to have an actual navigation being triggered, you should wrap your components in a [Navigator component](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html#content). These are a bit hard to get in the beginning but the recommended way to solve navigation.

If you have no real navigation but you would rather like to render the other component you may simply trigger setState to render the other component you would first have to require. [I built a small demo for you, I hope this helps.](https://rnplay.org/apps/wQQfbw)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm actually trying to pass some data to the new view. It is a list of books and I want to show book details when someone clicks on a book. I guess that I should use navigator.

Comment: In general, this would be better for this case. Maybe this post helps you: http://tech.taskrabbit.com/blog/2015/09/21/react-native-example-app/ (Please consider approving this answer ;) )